# Saving data from json to text file

Tags: javascript, html, json, web, raspberry-pi

I have some temperature data in an html page returned from a raspberry using can bus.
I want to save this data in a text file.
The information exist in a JS file :

```
socket.on('tempback', (data) => {

  $("#BTInfo").text(data);

});
```

and  i call it from the html so as to show it in an interface.

```
<div id="BPTInfo" class="number-circle text colortemp"> p id="BPTInf" style="vertical-align: middle;line-height: 1;margin-bottom: -1px;">0</p></div>
```

Please can you help me saving those data in a text file?